# Change password in RESTful API (Server validation on PATCH)

Tags: rest, http, authentication, web, http-patch

In a RESTful API I have user resources on `/users` and `/users/:id` with their usernames, email-addresses and passwords.

When I want to update a users information I can easily do a `PATCH:/users/:id` with some `JSONPatch` data.

The problem now is that I can't figure out how to handle a *change password* scenario with a `currentPassword`, `newPassword` and `newPasswordConfirm` form.

What METHOD should be used (PATCH seems appropriate but problematic) and in what way should the data be transmitted (body/header/...).

*In a wider scope - how should a patch with further fields for validation be handled.*

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231430/validate-change-password-via-rest-api) seems related but doesn't cover this exact topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `PATCH`, to partially update a *user* resource, have you ever considered `PUT` to replace the password?

Your endpoint could be `/users/:id/password`, where *password* is a sub resource of the *user* resource. And your request to replace the password would be like:

```
PUT /users/1/password HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com
Content-Length: 113
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0

{
    "currentPassword" : "secret",
    "newPassword": "othersecret",
    "newPasswordConfirm" : "othersecret"
}
```

Comment: I did consider this solution but wanted to avoid exposing the individual fields on the API. Apart from that I would rather use the `POST` method, since the `PUT` operation is defined to be idempotent while this operation would not clearly be.

Comment: Would you mind looking at my answer and providing feedback?

Answer (score 1):

After some deeper dive into [JSONPatch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) I was able to come up with the approach of adding `test` operations to the patch data.

This could look somewhat like:

```
[
    { "op": "test", "path": "/password", "value": "oldPassword" },
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/password", "value": "newPassword" },
    { "op": "test", "path": "/password", "value": "newPasswordConfirm" }
]
```

Are there any concerns using this method?

Comment: I think this approach will work fine. However, IMHO, the `PUT` approach makes it clearer.

Comment: Okay, one thing that might be a dealbreaker is the fact that I would have to assure that the consumer does actually use this request format. Without further server-side validation a consumer could just send the replace without the test cases.